# sorting database result object (array) according to months

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database that has newsletter entries that I want to arrange according to months. My db has the following fields id, title, description and date. The date has is the full date e.g. 2007-02-01 15:26:02. What I want to is to arrange all the newsletters according to the corresponding month e.g I want to have something like this

November 2010 
Title of Newsletter 
 
Title of Newsletter 
 ... Till all the title of the November 2010 newsletters are printed out

December 2010 
Title of Newsletter 
 
... Till all the title of the November 2010 newsletters are printed out

and so on.

Please could someone help me with the code that would achieve this or give me an idea on how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM db ORDER BY MONTH(date) AS 'd' desc GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

This is the query you are looking for, the rest is pretty basic php/sql so you should be able to look up a guide or something and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTHNAME(date), ' ', title) as title FROM newsletter ORDER BY date desc;
```

and then get the "title" field from the result

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

This function should help you do what you want to. You could use it to get the newsletters for a specific year, then order them by month.

SELECT * FROM sell_news WHERE DATE_FORMAT(news_date,'%Y')='2009' ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(news_date,'%m') ASC

Answer (score 0):

That is display logic that belongs in your PHP code. As long as you SELECT the newsletters ordered by date, you just need a line or two of code that says "if I already displayed that month name, don't display it again" as you loop through and print the newsletter titles. The people telling you to sort or group by the month in the query are leading you the wrong way.